# Object reference required for non-static field

Tags: c#, object, ms-word, office-interop

I am getting this error message in this context:

```
int left = 0;
            int top = 0;
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;
            Word.Range rng2 = rng;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window.GetPoint(out left, out top, out width, out height, rng);
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window is non static, you need to create a new instance of it in order to use it.

```
 //using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
                Word.Application application = this.Application;

                //Not sure how you create your application object, just including this incase you're not using VSTO
                //Word.Application application =
                //(Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
                //OR
                //Word.Application application = new Word.Application();

                Word.Range rng = application.ActiveDocument.Range();
                int left,top,width,height = 0;
                Word.Range rng2 = rng;
                application.ActiveWindow.GetPoint(out left, out top, out width, out height, rng);
```

**OR**

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window window = application.ActiveWindow;
            window.GetPoint(out left, out top, out width, out height, rng);
```

Comment: Thanks, Deni.   I had to look at what you were saying for a few minutes and think carefully about the point you were making.   Now, I understand perfectly.  For dummies like me, I guess the blue color of the first word in my example code (Microsoft) is a pretty good giveaway.  Thanks again!  :-)